# How do I resolve "incompatible library version" for mysql2 gem with ruby 2.3 on OS X?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

I'm using ruby 2.3, and in the gemfile, I've got the mysql2 gem listed. But when I try to run `rake db:migrate`, I get the following:

```
/Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.2/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle (fatal)
```

I can't seem to get around this one. I've installed Mysql 5.7 with Homebrew, tried updating the bundle, uninstalling and reinstalling the mysql2 gem, all to no avail.

How can I get this resolved?

Comment: i've got the same issue with the same gem version - i'm using sequel, not sure if you are or if it makes a difference.  have you resolved this issue?

Comment: also, using mariadbclient on arch linux

Comment: No, not yet. I'm using OS X.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I ended up solving this with `gem pristine --all`

Comment: great works. Would you please, explain why it wasn't working and how does this fixes that?

Comment: To understant what it does look https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-quick-gem-tricks/

Answer (score 8):

I have solved this with `gem pristine mysql2` followed by `spring stop`.

Answer (score 1):

running sudo gem pristine mysql2 did not work for me.

I had to uninstall and reinstall the mysql2 gem.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. I had ruby 2.3.4 installed and using rails 4.6.2.

There were two issues causes and the support team of the hosting company I was using helped me resolve the issue.

The first was that the mysql2 lib that was installed was, by default, linked to ruby 1.8  instead of ruby 2

```
# lld ../2.2.0/mysql2-0.4.4/mysql2/mysql2.so
... 
...
libruby.so.1.8 => /usr/lib64/libruby.so.1.8 (0x00007f2af1f8a000)
...
```

Second issue was to compile the lib with the installed mysql server config

So mysql2 gem had to be uninstalled and re-installed with the right ruby lib and compiled with the right mysql config.

Below are the commands.

```
gem uninstall mysql2
gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config --with-opt-lib=/where/my/ruby22/lib_was_located/
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem moving to Ubuntu 16.04

The following did the trick

```
sudo apt-get install g++
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was

gem install nokogiri -v 1.10.2

after that, it was fine.